# Set cell font on DataGridView before/as form is shown

Tags: c#, datagridview

**Background**

When I hit a button on a WinForm, I am loading data into a BindingSource that serves as the data source for a DataGridView.  Once the data is loaded, I go through and make some modifications to the DataGridView; in particular, I 1) set any cells that are valued as DBNull to the string value "NULL", 2) italicize the same cells, and 3) highlight some rows.

Simple example of what I'm doing:

```
private void btnFetch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // If there's already a DataSource, Dispose of it.
    if (bsMessageTracking.DataSource != null)
    {
        (bsMessageTracking.DataSource as DataTable).Dispose();
    }

    // Get new DataSource.
    bsMessageTracking.DataSource = GetDataTable(); // Details not relevant.

    // Show NULL values.
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            if (cell.Value is DBNull)
            {
                cell.Value = "NULL";
                cell.Style.Font = new Font(dgv.DefaultCellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
            }
        }
    }

    // Apply highlighting.
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvMessageTracking.Rows)
    {
        if (HighlightRow(row)) // Details not relevant.
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
        }
    }
}
```

The data gets loaded based on input into a TextBox on the form.

**Situation**

Everything works great if this occurs on the button click.  However, in order to provide some convenience to the user, I am allowing this form to get loaded with data prepopulated - the main form will instantiate this form with the data to put into the TextBox, and this btnFetch_Click handler will get called from the constructor:

```
internal MessageTracking(string ID)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Setup data source.
    dgvMessageTracking.DataSource = bsMessageTracking;

    // Set ID and run query.
    if (ID != null)
    {
        // Set ID.
        txtlID.Text = ID;

        // Run!
        btnFetch_Click(null, null);
    }
}
```

The value of the cells gets changed (so I see NULL), but the font and the highlighting don't stick.

**What I've tried**

If I replicate the highlighting code in the OnShown method, the highlighting sticks.  However, replicating the font code there doesn't work.  I can make the font stick if I put it in CellFormatting, but that seems like overkill to me, because I only need this to be run once when the form is loaded - it works fine if the process is run *after* the form is visible.

**Plea**

If anyone has any suggestions, I would appreciate them.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, from the lack of responses, that there is no better way if you want the formatting shown when the form first becomes visible.  I have removed the `Show NULL values` portion of the `btnFetch_Click` handler and added this `dgvMessageTracking_CellFormatting` handler to handle this functionality at all times:

```
private void dgvMessageTracking_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Value is DBNull)
    {
        e.Value = "NULL";
        e.CellStyle.Font = new Font(dgvMessageTracking.DefaultCellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the event handler you are using I would suggest using the dataGridView Cell_Formatting like @zimdanen. However, here is how I made it work.

```
    private void small8PtToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fontSize = 8;
        dataGridBatchHistory.Refresh();
    }
```

fontSize is an integer I used to set the font dynamically and you can set most properties this way. than i would call my CellFormatting function

```
    private void dataGridBatchHistory_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CellStyle.Font = new Font("Tahoma", fontSize);
    }
```

this would update my form with the new correct size upon clicking my toolstrip menu item. however i believe this works for many of the events you can create!